# How to load HTML file in webview with query string in iOS app device using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, query-string, xcode8.2, local-files

I have added html file in my project root, normally it is being loaded in web view easily. I am using below code:

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

It works fine.

Now I am to set query strings with path, to do this I have added below code:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?FirstName=dd&LastName=ee",filepath];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

It works in Mac and Desktop but not working in iOS devices and simulator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For your kind information [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] also works for local file.